# BibTex citing format: Hide Indices/key for CV

Tags: bibliographies

For my CV (pdflatex) I like to add my publications (BibTex) but a can't get rid of the keys/indices for the cite entrys. Unfortunately I like to use a special *mstyle.bst* file (I hadn't made myself)

```
%% This is file `mstyle.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility. - The original source files were:
%% merlin.mbs ... german.mbs ... merlin.mbs ...
```

What do I need to change to hide/remove this cite [keys]:

[image]

Example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Literatur.bib}  
 @article{article001,
   author = {Hans Mustermann},  
   title = {Einfach nur ein Titel},  
   number = {ABCD-E/2008/de/1234},  
   institution = {Firma AG},  
   year = {2008}  
 }  

 @article{article002,
   author = {Hans-Dieter Müller},  
   title = {Noch ein Titel},  
   number = {ABCD-E/2007/en/1234},  
   institution = {Firma AG},  
   year = {2007}  
 }  
 \end{filecontents*} 

 \documentclass{scrreprt} 
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 


 \begin{document} 
    %% -- CV Body --

     \bibliography{Literatur} % Bib File
     \bibliographystyle{plain} % I use my mstyle here

     \nocite{*} 

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by removing all list-related spacing, as well as remove the way the `\@biblabel` is being printed (just make if `\@gobble` it's argument):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}  
@article{article001,
  author = {Hans Mustermann},  
  title = {Einfach nur ein Titel},  
  number = {ABCD-E/2008/de/1234},  
  institution = {Firma AG},  
  year = {2008}  
}  

@article{article002,
  author = {Hans-Dieter Müller},  
  title = {Noch ein Titel},  
  number = {ABCD-E/2007/en/1234},  
  institution = {Firma AG},  
  year = {2007}  
}  
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document} 

\nocite{*} 

\bibliographystyle{plain} % bibliography style

\makeatletter
\setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
\let\@biblabel\@gobble
\makeatother

\bibliography{\jobname} % bibliography file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes \let\@biblabel\@gobble was the right thing! (and also the spacing is fixed well!) Thanks for your time! :-)